# I have something with my stored procedure? I want to cancat or add an "AND" based on an if statment but us mysql is not allowing me?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

When I run this code then mysql shows me an error of syntax that it is not allowed

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE `GetHotelByLocationArrivalDeparture`(IN strLocation VARCHAR(500),IN dateArrival DATE,IN dateDeparture DATE,IN strOrderBy VARCHAR(500),IN nMinPrice FLOAT,IN nMaxPrice FLOAT)
BEGIN 

SELECT
        HT.HotelId AS HotelId,
        HT.HotelName AS HotelName,
        HT.HotelDescription AS HotelDescription,
        HT.HotelLogo AS HotelLogo,
        HT.HotelStar AS HotelStar,
        HT.HotelLocation AS HotelLocation,
        HT.HotelLatitude AS HotelLatitude,  
        HT.HotelLongitude AS HotelLongitude,
        HT.AccomodationTypeId AS AccomodationTypeId,
        RM.RoomId AS RoomId,
        RM.RoomName AS RoomName,
        RM.RoomMaxPeople AS RoomMaxPeople,
        RM.RoomCurrency AS RoomCurrency,
        RM.RoomMinDays AS RoomMinDays,
        RM.RoomKeyInfo AS RoomKeyInfo,
        RM.RoomBedTypeOneId AS RoomBedTypeOneId,
        RM.RoomBedTypeTwoId AS RoomBedTypeTwoId,
        DR.DateRangeId AS DateRangeId,
        DR.DateRangeFromDate AS DateRangeFromDate,
        DR.DateRangeToDate AS DateRangeToDate,
        DR.DateRangeNote AS DateRangeNote,
        DR.CurrencyId AS DateRangeCurrencyId,
        DR.DateRangeMinNight AS DateRangeMinNight,
        DR.RoomId AS DateRangeRoomId,
        DRR.DateRowId AS DateRowId,
        DRR.DateRowNetRate AS DateRowNetRate,
        DRR.DateRowDiscount AS DateRowDiscount,
        DRR.DateRowDiscountedNet AS DateRowDiscountedNet,
        DRR.DateRowTax AS DateRowTax,
        DRR.DateRowHotelPrice AS DateRowHotelPrice,
        DRR.DateRowMarkup AS DateRowMarkup,
        DRR.DateRowClientPrice AS DateRowClientPrice,
        DRR.DateRowConvertedPrice AS DateRowConvertedPrice,
        DRR.DateRowType AS DateRowType
    FROM 
        tblhotel HT,
        tblroom RM,
        tbldaterange DR,
        tbldaterow DRR
WHERE 
        (
                LOWER(HT.HotelName) REGEXP TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM strLocation) 
             OR LOWER(HT.HotelLocation) REGEXP TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM strLocation)
        )  
    AND 
        (
            (
                    DR.DateRangeToDate > TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM dateArrival) 
                AND TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM dateDeparture) >  DR.DateRangeFromDate 
                AND TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM dateArrival)   >= DR.DateRangeFromDate
                AND TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM dateDeparture) <= DR.DateRangeToDate
            )
            OR
            (
                ( 
                    TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM dateDeparture) BETWEEN DR.DateRangeFromDate AND DR.DateRangeToDate
                ) 
                AND TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM dateDeparture) >  DR.DateRangeFromDate 
                AND TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM dateArrival)   >= DR.DateRangeFromDate
                AND TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM dateDeparture) <= DR.DateRangeToDate
            )
        )
    AND (HT.HotelId     = RM.HotelId)
    AND (RM.RoomId      = DR.RoomId)
    AND (DR.DateRangeId = DRR.DateRangeId)    
    AND 
        (       HT.IsActive = 1 
            AND HT.IsDeleted <> 1 
            AND RM.IsActive = 1 
            AND RM.IsDeleted <> 1 
            AND DR.IsActive = 1 
            AND DR.IsDeleted <> 1
        )
        /* This is what i want to do */
        IF (nMinPrice > AND nMaxPrice > 0) THEN
            AND DRR.DateRowClientPrice BETWEEN nMinPrice AND nMaxPrice
        END IF;    
        /* This is what i want to do */
        ORDER BY 
                CASE WHEN strOrderBy='sorthotelname_DESC' THEN HT.HotelName END DESC,  
                CASE WHEN strOrderBy='sorthotelname_ASC' THEN HT.HotelName END ASC,
                CASE WHEN strOrderBy='sorthotelstars_DESC' THEN HT.HotelStar END DESC,  
                CASE WHEN strOrderBy='sorthotelstars_ASC' THEN HT.HotelStar END ASC,
                CASE WHEN strOrderBy='sorthotelprice_DESC' THEN CONCAT(DRR.DateRowClientPrice ,'') END DESC,  
                CASE WHEN strOrderBy='sorthotelprice_ASC' THEN CONCAT(DRR.DateRowClientPrice ,'') END ASC,
                CASE WHEN strOrderBy='sorthotellocation_DESC' THEN HT.HotelLocation END DESC,  
                CASE WHEN strOrderBy='sorthotellocation_ASC' THEN HT.HotelLocation END ASC;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I'd love to be able to help you, but "us mysql shows an error" isn't a question, and I'm not sure what you're asking. It's a little hard to wade through that huge mess of unformatted code with no clear description of the problem or actual question being asked, trying to figure out what might be wrong. Please [edit] your question to include the *actual error message you're getting*. While you're doing that, you can click the little `?` button on the toolbar and get information about formatting code in your post so that it's readable, and make it so we can read it. :-)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please learn how to format code in questions and how to clearly formulate what's wrong with your code and what you want to be helped with.

Comment: Is this an appropriate place for a comment like "needs more Eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeek!"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mind reading.


Comment: Can you please check it right now as I have just formatted the code. Thanks

Comment: @H2CO3: I must be psychic then. Sure there is a lot of code there but a couple seconds of scanning it should make the problem obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can throw an `IF` into the middle of a WHERE clause like that. Instead, rework the logic so that your `IF` becomes a boolean expression, something like this perhaps:

```
and case
    when nMinPrice > 0 and nMaxPrice > 0 then
        DRR.DateRowClientPrice BETWEEN nMinPrice AND nMaxPrice
    else
        1
    end
```

If  your `nMinPrice` and `nMaxPrice` are positive, that CASE will have the value of:

```
DRR.DateRowClientPrice BETWEEN nMinPrice AND nMaxPrice
```

If one of `nMinPrice` or `nMaxPrice` is not positive, then that CASE will be `1` (i.e. true) and a logical conjunction with TRUE is a no-op so the CASE will effectively be ignored.

Comment: @peterm: Thanks. And thanks for being nice to the nube up in the comments.